# Changes to Micropython urequests/requests

Tags: micropython

I found this project to make a portable 3D printer monitor, using a D1 Mini and an OLED:
https://github.com/nmavor/klipper-esp8622/blob/master/main.py
It's a bare-bones implementation that just shows text on the screen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T31bh5aNVHc

My plan is to make it look better - add a progress bar, clean up the text presentation, etc.

It connects to Klipper/Moonraker's API and retrieves info about the state of the current print. Since it was put up on Github six months ago, there seem to be some updates in Micropython that keep it from working.

Running it in Thonny gets the following errors:

%Run -c $EDITOR_CONTENT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 39, in module
File "requests/init.py", line 180, in get
File "requests/init.py", line 76, in request

OSError: -2
```

I found that urequests has been updated to "requests" and added the new versions.
https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/tree/master/micropython/urequests

Line 39 in the source on Github is:
response = urequests.get(host+printer_api)

The error on line 180 refers to this in requests:
return request("GET", url, **kw)

The error on line 76 refers to this in requests:
ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)

I think I covered all the info. I'm still new to working with this stuff in Micropython, so any help is appreciated!